# TextField default value from parent not rendering on child

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I'm working on a form with Reactjs that gets some defaultValues from the parent component.

The problem is, the parent component set states of the values with a axios post and pass those values to the child as props. I can print those values on the child component with console.log but if I try to put those values on defaultValues on the TextFields I got a empty form, none of the values is rendered on the form.

Parent component:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
         somevalue: '',
      }
   }

   componentDidMount(){
      this.getData();
   }

   getData = async () => {
      await api.post('/getValue')
      .then((res) => {
         this.setState({
            someValue: res.data;
         })
      }).catch((err) => {
         console.log("Error: ", err);
      })
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <Child value={this.state.someValue}/>
      )}
}
```

Child component

```
export default function Child(props) {
   console.log(props.value); // THIS LOG PRINT THE VALUE PROPERLY
   return(
      <TextField defaultValue={props.value}/>
   )
}
```

This is basically my code structure, but it's not working. TextField still empty after this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The property `defaultValue` is only used on the initial render. If you'll inspect your code you'll see that before the console.log outputs the value it will first output `undefined`. You can either change it to a controlled component by changing `defaultValue` to `value`. This way the value will display, but you'll need to add an onChange handler for the changes to the value.

```
function Child(props) {
    // Using the value prop your value will display, but you will also have to pass an onChange handler to update the state in the parent
    return <TextField value={props.value} />;
}
```

Or you can wait until the value is available before rendering your component

```
const { someValue } = this.state;
if (!someValue) {
  return "loading the data";
}
return <Child value={someValue} />;
```

It depends on the exact situation what solution will be better. But I think it's likely you'll want to update the value in the input and do something with it, so I would go with the first situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir :D That's the trick! Just used "if (!someValue){}" and the defaultValue worked as needed.

Comment: Saw your edit on the answer and the second solution worked better for me because some of my loading elements. I am treating the values directly in the child component and sending back with axios to my server. Also, I'm not using the TextField value, but the defaultValue and worked as needed. Thank you again.